# SQL Server 2019 AOAG - ReadOnly ConnectionString Not working with error 80004005 Invalid connection string attribute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, read-only-routing

(I hope this is the proper place for posting, as it is about the database and its connection.)

SQL Server 2019 / ASP Classic / ASP.NET

I followed the information from this page. [ReadOnly Routing (sqlservercentral.com)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/configure-read-only-routing) and have everything set up and all tests passed in SQL Server for the AOAG.

With the ASP Classic ConnectionString test.
(Once I get the asp classic ConnectionString working, I will implement the asp.net version.)
With the below code, if I run the SQLListener,2433, the ConnectionString works.
(Makes testing easier, creating the Variable and going between them instead of changing it in the ConnectionString.)

```
'getSerInstance = "SQLListener,2433" ' Works
'getSerInstance = "sql1.domain.local,1433" ' Does not Work
'getSerInstance = "SQLListener,1433" ' Does not Work

Set siteconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
siteconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=tcp:"&getSerInstance&";
Database=dbname;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;
MultiSubnetFailover=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;Max Pool Size=1024;"
siteconn.Open
```

Running SQLListener,2433 works, but once I run either of the other two, I receive the error.

> > '80004005' Invalid connection string attribute.

Added: User ID=USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD; was the only way to make "SQLListener,2433" work. So it is left in, in hopes that it would also help to make one of the others work as well.

In each of the SQL Instances, the following Firewall rules are implemented.

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQLServer default instance" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 1433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow  
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "SQLServer Listener instance" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 2433 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
```

Comment: The [connection string attributes for MSOLEDBSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#using-idatainitializegetdatasource) should have spaces in the `Application Intent` and `Integrated Security' keywords.

Comment: It's also not possible to use a user id and integrated auth at the same time.

Comment: Hey, guys. I changed to: "Application Intent=ReadOnly;Integrated Security=SSPI;" and also removed the UN and PW, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Have a question since this is the first time dealing with this type of connection to SQL Server with both ReadOnly and ReadWrite. -- Q: The same connection string is used for both "ReadOnly and ReadWrite." How can you tell if the ReadOnly server takes the Select Statement request from the connection string when the page is loaded? It is easy to tell for the Write, as the data shows on the page when it is updated, or a new record is inserted. >>>How do you monitor the Always On for all connections to the SQL Instances, and who takes the connection?<<< Thanks.

Comment: "Always On availability groups is the full, formal name for this availability feature. The abbreviation is AG, not AOAG or AAG." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for the Info Hardcode, though it does not help in this issue.